# How to stay on the same page after a form submission integrated to a Google form

Tags: vue.js, form-submit, google-forms

In my website i have a contact form, and i've integrated it with a Google form. I've added the google form's execute URL as the action URL so once its submitted the form is being populated with the form data. [the way i have done it](https://blog.h-educate.com/how-to-send-an-email-in-a-static-html-page-using-google-sheets-scripts/)

But when its being submitted, its redirecting to a google form's response page. What i need is once its submitted, to stay on the same page and give an alert. Im not sure how to do this in vue js. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

the content on the redirected page

```
{"result":"success","data":"{\"name\":[\"sdvsdv\"],\"company\":[\"dsvdv\"]}"}
```

Form in vue js view

```
         <form method="POST" id="appointment-form" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzRHvjfmIZdwKnOm26PeFv64OyyyGAfcr68MxvYw/exec">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Your name" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" required>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Company name" name="company" class="form-control" id="company" required>
            </div>
              <buttontype="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block form-submit-btn">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: In `action` you're saying on Submit go to that `url`

Comment: @mamunmohamed yes, to change that i should use an AJAX request i suppose? is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

After read your code properly, i found many errors.

1. How are you saving input values?
   To save, you have to use ```v-model directive````

I guess you save the input values in somewhere. To avoid your problem, you can add a method and call it on submit, and inside the method save your input values.